# Placeholder in bash/shell for defferent linux distr

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell, shell-scripting

i have some problem. I need to add in autorun of linux, some scripts. But in my infrastructure, i have a different distrs. Of course, the way of adding this scripts in autorun different. In CentOS it is chkconfig, in debian/ubuntu it is update-rc.d.
So, i have some script:

```
    function autorun () {
    if [ -f /etc/debian_version ]; then
       os="Debian $(cat /etc/debian_version)"
       echo $os
       update-rc.d ${i} defaults"
    elif [ -f /etc/redhat-release ]; then
       os=`cat /etc/redhat-release`
       echo $os
       chkconfig --add ${i}"
    else
       os="$(uname -s) $(uname -r)"
       echo $os
       echo "Other OS. Please check type of autorun in your OS"
    fi
    }

    $i=nginx

    autorun $i
```

Yes, it's works. Can i write this without variable declaration, like this:

```
autorun nginx
```

Please help, may be you can propose other way, that will be good. Thanks.

Comment: you have a quote too much in line 5: `update-rc.d ${i} defaults"`. same below at `chkconfig --add ${i}"`

Answer (score 1):

In `bash`, parameters to functions are available in the variables `$1`, `$2` etc,

```
function ar () 
{
    echo $1
}
```

would result in

```
> ar Hello
Hello

> ar Hello World
Hello

> ar "Hello World"
Hello World
```

I believe that's what you are after, but if not, edit your question to make it more clear.